# Trying to update my part table within my database with an update statement and a where clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update my part table where `item_class = HW` and I cant get it right. Can anyone see what is wrong with my syntax.

```
update part
set unit_price = unit_price + 1.05
where item_class = ' HW ' ;
```

It provides no error, but it doesn't update the correct rows. It say it is going to update 0 rows when in fact needs to update 4 rows.

Comment: you have two space around yuor HW  .. is this right?

Comment: NO it isn't right thank you very much

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. You've repeated the tags, which is totally useless, and removing them leaves *(update statement)*, which is useless. Your title should explain the problem you're asking or problem you're having in a way that will be meaningful to future users here who see it in a search result.

Comment: Ok sir i do apologize for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you have wrong space  try  using

```
update part
set unit_price = unit_price + 1.05
where item_class like  '*HW*' ;
```

or

```
update part
set unit_price = unit_price + 1.05
where item_class like  '* HW *' ;
```

or

```
update part
set unit_price = unit_price + 1.05
where item_class = 'HW' ;
```

Comment: Yes i removed the spaces and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much i feel silly for putting those spaces in and never realizing it.

Comment: I used the last one.

Comment: Access uses * not % as a wild card.see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Examples-of-wildcard-characters-939e153f-bd30-47e4-a763-61897c87b3f4

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your data it is hard to say  but I see several possible problems. One is the spaces around ' HW '. Depending on what is in that field it is hard to say for sure what the correct where clause would be. If the HW is part of a longer group of characters (people sometimes mistakenly store comma delimited lists in Access fields), you might need to use teh LIKE function instead. Or it could be that removing teh unneeded spaces will fix teh problem. So start with select statements:

```
Select * from part where item_class = ' HW ' ;
Select * from part where item_class = 'HW' ;
Select * from part where item_class like '*HW' ;
Select * from part where item_class like 'HW*' ;
Select * from part where item_class like '*HW*' ;
```

Once you find the one that returns the records you want, then use that in your update statement.

Something else I see that could cause issues is:

```
set unit_price = unit_price + 1.05
```

If Unit price can be NULL, you need to convert that to a 0 value for the sum to work. Otherwise NULL plus any amount = NUll. The following could work.

```
set (IIf([unit_price] Is Null, 0, [unit_price]))+1.05
```

Comment: Yes the second one works. It was those unintended spaces. Thank you